# RegEx Match Wildcard Subdirectory

Tags: regex, nginx

We are trying to use regex in a nginx location block to match all jpg images in the following file structure where the fourth subdirectory is an unique id. This is what we tried but it's not correct. Can someone explain how to match this in regex?

```
/media/photos/thumbs/00001/1.jpg

location ~ /media/photos/thumbs/(^\d+$)\/*.(jpg){
                
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible for the RegExp you have currently to match, since the `^` (start of string) token and the `$` (end of string) token both appear in the middle of the string you're trying to match.

Overall, you'll need to make a few changes:

1. Remove the start/end assertion tokens (`^` and `$`) from the middle of the pattern
2. Include a token (`\d`, a digit) and quantifier (`+`, one or more) to match the numeric filename of the file itself

This would look something like:

```
location ~ /media/photos/thumbs/(\d+)/\d+\.(jpg) {
    # configuration
}
```

You might also be able to remove the capture groups if you're not actually doing anything in the config with the captured data.

Comment: thanks for the explanation but it's still not matching.

Comment: @master00 Using an [nginx location match tester](https://nginx.viraptor.info/) shows that this pattern does indeed work with the test case you provided; is the test case you're using the same as in your original post? If not, can you share what test *is* failing with the pattern included above?

Comment: thanks for the link. it was a problem with the order of the location block not the expression. thanks for that. regex hurts my head.